# Can google follow javascript generated link?

Tags: javascript, html, css, seo

I created four website by HTML and CSS and JavaScript (I am not using server side language PHP or else).

All my purpose is to get back link with some variable link and link text. So I decided to use a single java script and refer my websites to that link.

Following javascript file generated link like this

```
<script>

var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "my title text";
a.href = "http://example.com";
document.body.appendChild(a);

</script>
```

Question is that does google crawler follow this link. In fact does it have SEO benefit?

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner: when formatting on Stack Overflow, backticks (\`) are for inline code (like `var myString = "Hello";`), not for... whatever you were trying to do with them in your edit.

Comment: Got it ! I will be careful from next time.

Comment: what happened here? :D

Comment: wait.. didn't I already answer this like 30 minutes ago? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18845519#18845519

Comment: almost, John Conde say it hasn't additional SEO benefit. i just want to know what doesn't he means about additional SEO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> all the question is that does google crwader follow this link.

Yes. [Google can process JavaScript](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html) so this link would be available to them to follow and crawl.

> in fact does it have seo benefit?

No. There is no SEO benefit to doing this.

Comment: can u explain more why it doesn't have any seo benefit

Comment: we get back link with related site and getting traffic by this way

Comment: The link will have SEO benefit just like any other link will. But creating it with JavaScript will not offer any additional SEO benefit.

Comment: what kind of additional SEO benefit do u mean?

Comment: Some people thing that an arbitrary bonus can occur if they do "X". But there are no arbitrary bonuses in SEO. Nothing is "special" just because Google says so. Anything that is a ranking factor is so for a reason.

Comment: The linked page seems to say just that Google has started executing some JavaScript. Where does it say that Google processes links created with JavaScript and follows them?

Comment: If they process the JavaScript they can see the links. Why wouldn't they follow them? If they're gonna handle Ajax applications and dynamic content, they're going to follow the links they produce as well.